# Search a value which in an JSON Object and return the value based on the conditon from Json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a json object of below type,

```
var jsondata = {
"intents": [
        {
            "intent": "welcome",
            "examples": [{
                "text": "Hi"
                },
                {
                "text": "Hello"
                }
            ]
        }
        ],
"dialog_nodes": [{
    "condition": "welcome",
    "output": [{
            "response_type": "text",
            "text": "Hello"
        },
        {
            "response_type": "text",
            "text": "How Can I help you"
        }

    ]
}]
}
```

Now I have a string variable say,

```
var input = "Hi"
```

If this string matches any "examples" in "intents" object then specific "intent" value should be taken and then in "dialog_nodes" output should be returned if intents[].intent == dialog_nodes[].condition

So for example

```
If input = "Hi";
Then, it should return

[{
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "Hello"
    },
    {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "How Can I help you"
    }

]
```

Can someone please help on this

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

We can find the matched intents first,then query the condition by the matched intents.

Below is a reference for you

```js
var jsondata = {
"intents": [
        {
            "intent": "welcome",
            "examples": [{
                "text": "Hi"
                },
                {
                "text": "Hello"
                }
            ]
        }
        ],
"dialog_nodes": [{
    "condition": "welcome",
    "output": [{
            "response_type": "text",
            "text": "Hello"
        },
        {
            "response_type": "text",
            "text": "How Can I help you"
        }

    ]
}]
}

let input = 'Hi'
let intents = jsondata.intents.filter(i => i.examples.some(e => e.text === input)).map(i => i.intent)

let result = jsondata.dialog_nodes.filter(i => intents.some(e => e === i.condition)).map(e => e.output)
console.log(result)
```